# STML151RB I2C start condition sent but SB not set

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32l

I have a custom board with an STM32L151RB. I want to use I2C in master mode with [standard peripheral library](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-stm32077.html). I've started by copying chunks of code from demo project.

The problem is that the start condition is sent (confirmed with a logic analyzer), but the SB (start bit) in I2C_SR (status register) is never set.

I have 4k7 pullups. I2C lines **change state separately** (so they are not shorted to anything, GPIOs seem to be configured okay and I2C peripheral has clock enabled):
[image]

I dump I2C registers in my busy waiting loop and always get (hex):

```
I2C1->CR1=00000501
I2C1->CR2=00000002
I2C1->SR1=00000000
```

This is my init code:

```
void i2c_init(void){
    //enable clock to I2C peripheral
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);

    //configure pins in alternate mode (GPIO clock is already enabled in pins_init)
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_AF_I2C1, GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7);

    GPIO_InitTypeDef g;

    //PB6, PB7 - output, open drain, fast
    g.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7;
    g.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    g.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    g.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD;
    g.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &g);

    I2C_InitTypeDef init;

    init.I2C_ClockSpeed = 100000;
    init.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;
    init.I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2;
    init.I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0x00;
    init.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable;
    init.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;

    I2C_Init(I2C1, &init);
    I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);
}
```

This is my master code:

```
  I2C_ClearFlag(I2C1, I2C_FLAG_AF);
  I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2C1, ENABLE);

  /*!< Send I2C1 START condition */
  I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);

  /*!< Test on I2C1 EV5 and clear it */
  while ((!I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1,I2C_FLAG_SB)))  /*!< EV5 */
  {
    debugf("----busy wait----");
    debugf("I2C1->CR1=%08X", (unsigned int)I2C1->CR1);
    debugf("I2C1->CR2=%08X", (unsigned int)I2C1->CR2);
    debugf("I2C1->SR1=%08X", (unsigned int)I2C1->SR1);
    delay_ms(150); //this delay does not change anything (just limits debug terminal speed)
  } //this loop never exits
```

Why can the start bit in status register not be set after the GPIOs have successfully transmitted a start condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that it is a GPIO configuration issue. [Using this code](https://rafpe.ninja/2017/03/03/stm32-adventures-communication-using-i2c/) it turned out that my line:

```
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_AF_I2C1, GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7);
```

set registers incorrectly. The correct way to setup I2C on PB6/PB7 is:

```
GPIOB->AFR[0] |= ( 1 << 30 ) | ( 1 << 26); // P6/P7 => AF4
```

Now I2C works fine.

**UPDATE**

Ahh.... the joys of C type safety. The proper invocation of ST library function is:

```
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_I2C1);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_I2C1);
```

1. `GPIO_Pin_6` and `GPIO_PinSource6` are different defines
2. Pin argument comes second
3. Alternate functions argument comes third
4. Pins have to be configured one-by-one

Lesson learned: **use enums for your own code arguments instead of magic numbers!**